# Building an ArrayList in an external class - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

I have an `ArrayList` defined in `Class A`. Then I want to build  this array in `Class B` and use it in `Class A`.

I defined the ArrayList as:

```
Public arrayList As ArrayList
```

Then, in `Class B` I do:

```
Dim trLogkEmpty As New A
'Loop with strEspece definition
    trLogkEmpty.arrayList.Add(strEspece)
'End Loop
```

The program throws me this error:

> NullReferenceException

I don't know why, because `strEspece` has never become null (I tested it). I don't know if there is another reason.

Also, when I loop through the `arrayList` elements in `Class A`, I get again `NullReferenceException`. This is the loop code:

```
For Each logkNull In Me.arrayElemWithLogkEmpty
    Console.WriteLine(logkNull)
 Next
```

I don't know what happens with the first exception, but the code runs "correctly". In the second exception I guess that is something like I'm loosing the elements values of the array. I don't know how to solve it...any help? I accept different ways to solve it!

Comment: Does your constructor for class A initialise `arrayList`?

Comment: In ClassA you need to create an instance of the ArrayList. For example `Public arrayList As New ArrayList`

Comment: No, the NRE is more likely because `trLogkEmpty` or `arrayList` is not initialized, not `strEspece` - we lack any context for this though with no real code. See also [NullReference Exception in Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452) for help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two of the same mistake. A `NullReferenceException` means that you are attempting to access a property or method on an object that hasn't been instantiated yet. You are attempting to access both `A` and `A.arrayList` without first creating new instances of them.

So, instead of just:

```
trLogkEmpty.arrayList.Add(strEspece)
```

You should have:

```
Dim trLogkEmpty As New A()
trLogkEmpty.arrayList = New ArrayList()
trLogkEmpty.arrayList.Add(strEspece)
```

**However,** I must insist that you avoid `ArrayList`, and also that you avoid instantiating a public member of a class from outside that class. I would suggest using a strongly-typed collection class such as `List(Of T)`, and having a read-only property in `A`'s take care of its instantiation and visibility so the collection (not its contents) can't be modified outside of `A`:

```
Public Class A

    Private _myList As IList(Of String)

    Public ReadOnly Property MyList As IList(Of String)
        Get
            If _myList Is Nothing Then
                _myList = New List(Of String)
            End If
            Return _myList
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

And now you have:

```
Dim trLogkEmpty As New A()
trLogkEmpty.MyList.Add(strEspece)
```

You're probably going to need to keep your instance of `A` around, so class `B` should probably look somewhat like:

```
Public Class B

    Private _a As A

    Public Sub New()
        _a = New A()
    End Sub

    ' ... your methods that use _a.MyList

End Class
```

Comment: The OP states that an instance of ClassA has been created `Dim trLogkEmpty As New ClassA`. It does seem likely that no instance of the ArrayList has been created (since that is the only other possibility).

Comment: @Blackwood: Ah, yeah... missed that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally. When I initialised the array in class 'A' I forget to create an instance of ArrayList class, specifically, I forget to put `New`:

```
Public arrayElemWithLogkEmpty As New ArrayList
```

So, partly, @Blackwood was right!

Thank you all and forgive me for my basic knowledge about vb.net.

Comment: I put the `Shared` keyword for the `arrayList` and declared `As New`, so I solved the problem with it.

Comment: You made it a static member of class A, but are accessing it from class B. Is there any reason that it can't just be a member of Class B from the start?

Comment: Yes, that is what I jus finally did. I declared the ArrayList as `Public Shared` in class B. Then I instantiate this variable in class A as:

`B.arrayList.Count`

For example.